# R falsely identifying abundance data as presence/absence data (fossil package)

Tags: r, fossil

I am attempting to use the spp.est function of the package called "fossil" in RStudio. I have created a matrix called "akimiskibb" of abundance data with species as the columns and sites as the rows. When I try to use the function spp.est, I type this:

spp.est(akimiskibb, rand = 10, abund = TRUE, counter = FALSE, max.est = 'all')

The problem comes in because my abundance data has a lot of zeroes, so I get this error message:

Error in if (max(x) == 1) warning("cannot use incidence data for abundance-based analyses. If the data is incidence based, please run this function again with the option of 'abund=FALSE'") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

This function has worked in the past with matrices with a lot of zeroes (which are also abundance data, not presence/absence). I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Has anyone experienced something similar and found a way around this?

Thank you,

Kayla

Data:
matrix format:

```
 *sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5 sp6 sp7 sp8 sp9 sp10 sp11 sp12 sp13 sp14 sp15 sp16 sp17
 sample1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    0    0    0    0    0    1    
 0    0
 sample 2   0   0   0   1   0   0   1  25   7    0   18   12    0    0    0    
 1    1
 sample3    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0    0    3    1    0    0    0    
 5    4
 sp18 sp19 sp20 sp21 sp22 sp23 sp24 sp25 sp26 sp27 sp28 sp29 sp30 sp31 
 sp32
 sample1     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    
 0    0
 sample 2    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    2    
 0    3
 sample3     0    0    1    0    0   11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    
 0    1
 sp33 sp34 sp35 sp36 sp37 sp38 sp39 sp40 sp41 sp42 sp43  X
 sample1     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 NA
 sample 2    0    0    3    2    1    0    0    1    8    0    0 NA
 sample3     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 NA*
```

dput:

```
 *structure(list(sp1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp3 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), sp4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), sp5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp6 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), sp7 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), sp8 = c(1L, 25L, 3L), sp9 = c(0L, 
 7L, 0L), sp10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp11 = c(0L, 18L, 3L), sp12 = c(0L, 
 12L, 1L), sp13 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp14 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp15 = c(1L, 
 0L, 0L), sp16 = c(0L, 1L, 5L), sp17 = c(0L, 1L, 4L), sp18 = c(0L, 
 1L, 0L), sp19 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp20 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), sp21 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), sp22 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp23 = c(0L, 0L, 11L), sp24 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), sp25 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp26 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp27 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), sp28 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp29 = c(0L, 3L, 0L), sp30 = c(0L, 
 2L, 0L), sp31 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp32 = c(0L, 3L, 1L), sp33 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), sp34 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp35 = c(0L, 3L, 0L), sp36 = c(0L, 
 2L, 0L), sp37 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), sp38 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), sp39 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), sp40 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), sp41 = c(0L, 8L, 0L), sp42 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), sp43 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), X = c(NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("sp1", 
 "sp2", "sp3", "sp4", "sp5", "sp6", "sp7", "sp8", "sp9", "sp10", 
 "sp11", "sp12", "sp13", "sp14", "sp15", "sp16", "sp17", "sp18", 
 "sp19", "sp20", "sp21", "sp22", "sp23", "sp24", "sp25", "sp26", 
 "sp27", "sp28", "sp29", "sp30", "sp31", "sp32", "sp33", "sp34", 
 "sp35", "sp36", "sp37", "sp38", "sp39", "sp40", "sp41", "sp42", 
 "sp43", "X"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("sample1", 
 "sample 2", "sample3"))*
```

packages used:

fossil (made in R version 3.4.4)

Version of R: R x64 3.4.1

Comment: Welcome to SO--please post your data in a reproducible format using `dput()`.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello. I have edited the question with my data. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Check out the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, not familiar with this package so thank you for introducing it to me.  Always great to see how R is being used in so many disciplines.

I see two issues with your applications.  First, according to the `fossil` documentation for `spp.est`, your data needs to have your samples as columns and your species as rows.  The second issue is the "species" X with the `NA` values.  You need to get rid of these because the function can't handle them.

Here's the code:

```
library(fossil)
library(tidyverse)

akimiskibb <- as.data.frame(t(akimiskibb)) %>%
 filter(!is.na(sample1) == T)

spp.est(akimiskibb, rand = 10, abund = TRUE, counter = FALSE, max.est = 'all')

# which results in 

     N.obs S.obs S.obs(+95%) S.obs(-95%) Chao1 Chao1(upper) Chao1(lower)
[1,]     1  11.8    25.30995   -1.709948 20.90     28.38331     13.41669
[2,]     2  16.0    25.46770    6.532301 27.15     33.37680     20.92320
[3,]     3  20.0    20.00000   20.000000 26.00     29.24037     22.75963
          ACE ACE(upper) ACE(lower)    Jack1 Jack1(upper) Jack1(lower)
[1,] 14.56286   31.16289  -2.037175 16.82501     36.43129    -2.781268
[2,] 19.19286   30.64000   7.745713 22.21008     35.28448     9.135677
[3,] 22.28571   22.28571  22.285714 25.95082     25.95082    25.950820
attr(,"data.type")
[1] "abundance"
Warning messages:
1: In ests[[k]](b) :
  This data appears to be presence/absence based, but this estimator is for abundance data only
2: In ests[[k]](b) :
  This data appears to be presence/absence based, but this estimator is for abundance data only
```

Comment: Thank you Ben G. So I have to download the package tidyverse first, right?

Comment: Only to use the `%>%` function.  It's a really great function for doing data science/analysis.  If I answered your question, mark it as answered so it can be closed out.

Comment: When i try this, it tells me "Error in filter(!is.na(sample1) == T) : object 'sample1' not found". Any thoughts? I have to do this for 2 more matrices in the exact same format as akimiskibb, but this error message pops up for all of them.

Comment: Whoops never mind, I figured it out. I will mark this as answered. Thank you so much.